# Salvar dados do form em cookie e popular form com esses dados após reload da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Tenho uma pagina com filtros, sendo 4 selects, um input search, 2 input date e um submit, preciso manter os dados selecionados após o reload da pagina.

Ou seja coloco os dados para filtrar e após clicar no submit e a pagina carregar preciso que ela mantenha os valores do form conforme selecionado antes do submit.

A principio to salvando em cookie com o código abaixo, porem apesar de estar salvando os cookie blz queria saber se tem como diminuir esse código? Tipo em vez de usar um `$.cookie` para cada input, usar um para o form todo.

E também gostaria de saber como popular o form de novo com os dados do cookie e se isso não pode me causa problemas ele ficando armazenado, tem como excluir os cookies depois de usá-los?

```js
$(".searchButton").on("click", function () {
 $.cookie('frachiseesValue', $("#frachisees_filter").val());
 $.cookie('schoolsValue', $("#schools_filter").val());
 $.cookie('challengeValue', $("#post_challenges_filter").val());
 $.cookie('statusValue', $("#statuses_filter").val());
 $.cookie('searchValue', $("#filter_search").val());
 $.cookie('startDateValue', $("#startDate").val());
 $.cookie('endDateValue', $("#endDate").val());
});
```

**Update**

OBS: Esta sendo salvo no cookie (dos select) o id correspondente ao option e nao a string.

Answer (score -1):

Para carregar o select, faça assim.

1- Carregue os campos do select (todos os itens do **select**)

```js
$(function(){
    $("#frachisees_filter").val($.cookie('frachiseesValue'));
 $("#schools_filter").val($.cookie('schoolsValue'));
});
```

E assim sucessivamente para todos os outros selects

Comment: Não deu certo =/, Editei a pergunta coloquei uma obs e talvez pode ser o motivo por não da certo.

Answer (score -2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name">
      <br>
      <label class="form-label">Option</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="option" name="option">
        <option value="A1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="A2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="A3">Value 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar" />
    <input type="button" id="btn-load" class="btn btn-success" value="Carregar" />
  </form>
```

JS

```
$("#btn-save").click(function (e) {

  // obtem um array com os dados do formulario
  let data = $("#form").serializeArray();

  // transforma o array em um JSON e salva no localStorage do browser
  localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(data));

});

$("#btn-load").click(function (e) {

  // le o que tem salvo no localStorage
  let values = localStorage.getItem('form');

  // se existir algo
  if (values) {
    // transforma novamente em um array os dados do JSON salvo
    let data = JSON.parse(values);

    // percorre o array e atribui ao formulário os dados
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
      $(`#${item.name}`).val(item.value);

      // apenas para debug
      console.log(item.name, item.value)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Em sua pergunta, você citou vários tipos de campos HTML, mas não postou nenhum. Portanto, apenas para fins didáticos, vou assumir que todos os campos eram do tipo texto, além disso, o código abaixo é capaz de gravar e ler os dados via cookie, sem falar que é uma forma de reduzir o uso do termo "cookie" deixando o código mais limpo e legível:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Form Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Form Page</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="frachisees_filter">Franchisees:</label>
        <input type="text" id="frachiseesValue" name="frachiseesValue">
        <br>
        <label for="schoolsValue">Schools:</label>
        <input type="text" id="schoolsValue" name="schoolsValue">
        <br>
        <label for="post_challenges_filter">Challenge:</label>
        <input type="text" id="challengeValue" name="challengeValue">
        <br>
        <label for="statuses_filter">Status:</label>
        <input type="text" id="statusValue" name="statusValue">
        <br>
        <label for="filter_search">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" id="searchValue" name="searchValue">
        <br>
        <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="startDateValue" name="startDateValue">
        <br>
        <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="endDateValue" name="endDateValue">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="searchButton">Search</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const valuesToGet = [
                "frachiseesValue",
                "schoolsValue",
                "challengeValue",
                "statusValue",
                "searchValue",
                "startDateValue",
                "endDateValue"
            ];
            for (const key of valuesToGet) {
                const value = $.cookie(key);
                if (value) {
                    $(`#${key}`).val(value);
                }
            }
        });

        $(".searchButton").on("click", function () {
            const valuesToSet = {
                frachiseesValue: $("#frachiseesValue").val(),
                schoolsValue: $("#schoolsValue").val(),
                challengeValue: $("#challengeValue").val(),
                statusValue: $("#statusValue").val(),
                searchValue: $("#searchValue").val(),
                startDateValue: $("#startDateValue").val(),
                endDateValue: $("#endDateValue").val()
            };
            for (const key in valuesToSet) {
                $.cookie(key, valuesToSet[key]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Talvez deva considerar "sanitizar" a entrada do usuário antes de exibir o conteúdo do cookie no formulário.